# Haskell select kth element

Tags: haskell

Want to select the kth element from a list, can calling the function like so

```
selectN 5 aList
```

and the function I have

```
selectN :: Int -> a -> a
selectN 1 (x:_) = x
selectN [] _     = error "Index out of bounds"
selectN k (_:xs) 
  | n < 1           = error "Index out of bounds"
  | otherwise       = selectN xs (n - 1)
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to get the function correct. Currently have something like 
'selectN :: Int -> [a] -> a'
'selectN i list = (i) !! list' 
which throws the  Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `(i)'

Comment: nevermind, fixed with selectN :: Int -> [a] -> a  selectN i list = list !! (i-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so there are a few problems with your code so first, lets go through the issues:

```
selectN :: Int -> a -> a --You take in a list of a ie [a] and return a. So this is bit off
selectN 1 (x:_) = x 
selectN [] _     = error "Index out of bounds" -- Fine but not strictly needed
selectN k (_:xs) 
  | n < 1           = error "Index out of bounds" 
  | otherwise       = selectN xs (n - 1) --You've got the params backwards here.
```

So to fix this, first a good type signature:

```
selectN :: Int -> [a] -> a
```

Now the base case:

```
selectN 1 (x:_) = x --I would suggest using 0 not 1. 
                    --Most things in Haskell are 0 based.
selectN n (x:xs) = selectN (n-1) xs
```

So that works, No helpful error messages, but you can figure out how to add those back in.

It's also easy to do this with `(!!)` which has a type signature of

```
(!!) :: [a]->Int->a
```

so

```
selectN = flip (!!)
```

Check out [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) it's useful for these sort of things.

Answer (score 1):

To select the kth element of a list just use `!!`. The first element is index `0`

```
selectN = (!!)

ghci> let test = "abracadabra"
ghci> test !! 0   
ghci> 'a'
ghci> test !! 9
ghci> 'r'
```

but be careful about the `indexOutOfRange` Exception

```
ghci> test !! 11 
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large
```

**Edition : making the function safe**

It possible to write a `safeSelectN` to handle the error exception and allow the program to safely continu without any `IO` action. To do that one needs the following modifications

```
safeSelectN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
safeSelectN n xs = if null xs || length xs < n then [] else [xs !! n]
```

In this case the error will be detect by receiving an empty list as result.

```
ghci> safeSelectN 3 ""
[]
ghci> safeSelectN 0 ""
[]
ghci> safeSelectN 3 "abcd" --like this
['d']
```

Therefore when the result is correct you will not end up only with the kth element but with a list containing only the kth element.

Comment: Do you have a quick way to check for this and throw the proper error?

Comment: to trow out a proper error one need to adapt the output result type. for example that need to change type of selectN to `selectN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` where the result will be an empty list if error occurs. see detail inn my edited response